# React Redux doesn't update initialState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've been trying to apply Redux in my React Native app, but the initialState just doesn't update, and when I run the code it returns `mapStateToProps() in Connect(List) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.` and `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.state')`.
I'm still learning and this is where I got so far.
The goal is to let the user type `name` and `lastname` and insert in the array `list` and use `dispatch` to update the initialState `list` in the reducer
Thank you in advance for your answers.

**SCREEN**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateList } from './action'

export class List extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: this.props.list,
      name: '',
      lastname: '',
      
        };
  }


  addItem = ( name, lastname ) => {   
  
    const  item = {
        key: Math.random(),
        name: name,
        lastname: lastname,
      };
      this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, item]})
  };

  submitItem = ( list ) => {
    () => this.props.dispatch(updateList(list));
     this.props.navigation.navigate('list');
  }

  render(){
    return(
 
        <Button onPress={() => {this.addItem(this.state.name, this.state.lastname); this.submitItem(this.state.list)}}>
         <Text>Press Submit</Text>
        </Button>

    )}

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return this.state
}

mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateList
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List );
```

**ACTION.JS**

```
export const updateList = (list) => {
  return { type:"UPDATE_LIST", payload:list}
}
```

**REDUCER.JS**

```
const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  list: [],
};



    export const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type){
          case USER_STATE_CHANGE:
            return {
              ...state,
              currentUser: action.currentUser,
            };
          case 'UPDATE_LIST': 
          return{
            ...state,
            list: [...action.payload],
          }
          default:
            return state
      }
      
    };
```

Comment: Are your map state and dispatch functions class members? I don't see a `const` in front.. if so they'll be out of scope for `connect`

Comment: How can I fix that?

Comment: Move it? I don't even know for sure that's the issue. The code you posted is missing a `}` and depending on where that's at changes things.

Answer (score -2):

```
case 'UPDATE_LIST':
        return {
            ...state,
            list: action.payload,
        }
```

Just Try this.